# Information from a foreign table won't display in a textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

Information from a foreign table won't display while running my SQL statement in VBA.

```
Dim licenseplate As String
Dim stmt As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim results As DAO.Recordset

licenseplate = Text0

stmt = "SELECT Brand.Brand_name, Car.Car_model, Car.Car_color, Car.Car_buildyear, Car.Car_licenseplate " & _
            "FROM Brand INNER JOIN Car ON Brand.[Brand_ID] = Car.[Brand_ID] " & _
            "WHERE (((Car.Car_licenseplate)= """ & licenseplate & """))"


Set db = CurrentDb

Set results = db.OpenRecordset(stmt)
Set Me.[Tekst131].Recordset = results
```

I expect it to show me the Brand name, Car model, Car color, Car buildyear and Car license plate.

The actual output only shows Car model, Car color, Car buildyear and Car license plate.

It won't output any error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Increase the column count in the listbox/combox, or set the columnwidth of the first column to something larger than zero.

Comment: Thanks!! I feel so stupid for having the columnwidth on 0...

Comment: Is this combobox/listbox used for data entry? Why is Brand_ID not included as first field in SELECT?  Are you not saving Brand_ID as foreign key? If this is setting RowSource of a combo or list box, why reference to Recordset? Is this VBA or VB?

Comment: My program is designed in a way that if an user inputs a license plate number into the designated textbox it'll select the brand_name, car_model, etc. After everything is selected I display it in a textbox with Row source type set to Table/query. Brand_ID is the foreign key but I don't want to display that onto the screen so I don't select it.  It's VBA in Office 365 Acces